# Trying to figure out meaning of JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

Im trying to figure out this piece of code.
The code i am using the localStorage to output a dynamic table

what i understand.
1. if statement with a condition if localstorage is empty it pushes the array into localstorage
2. stringify the EmployeeList
3. Setting localStorage with Key, value pair
4. appending a ID tag to a HTML page

What i do not understand
1. why not use localStorage.setitem and setting the localStorage first, and then using the get method
2. why is the code parsed?

```
if(localStorage.getItem("Employee") == null) {
    var employeeList = [];
    employeeList.push (new Employee("Simon", "Male", "HR", 1999, "SM1@cbs.dk"));
    employeeList.push (new Employee("Mads", "Male","IT", 1999,  "MS@cbs.dk"));
    employeeList.push (new Employee("Jessica", "Female", "Sales",1998, "JT@cbs.dk"));
    employeeList.push (new Employee("Benjamin", "Male","IT", 1997, "BN@cbs.dk"));

    var employeeListString = JSON.stringify(employeeList);
    localStorage.setItem("Employee", employeeListString);
    document.querySelector("#employees").appendChild(buildTable(employeeList));
} else {
    var employeeList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Employee"));
}
```

Comment: Because... the list is either created or retrieved, meaning it can be modified and the state of it saved. If you run `setItem` first all the time, then what's the point in storing it in the first place?

Comment: Looks like default values to me, in case nothing was set yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From top to bottom:

- Checks if the local storage contains the key "Employee"

IF NO:

- Creates an array of employees
- Transforms this array into a string (`JSON.stringify`)
- Stores the string containing all employees into the local storage
- Displays in the DOM the list of employees via the method `buildTable(employeeList)`

IF YES:

- Recreates an array of employees from the local storage (`JSON.parse`)

Answer (score 2):

**1)** The code checks if the `localStorage` item exists before trying to add it, presumably to avoid unnecessary `stringify` and storage of the object.

**2)** The `employeeList` is set with `JSON.parse` because it's stored as a string in `localStorage`. So when reading it from `localStorage`, that JSON string is parsed to an actual JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

> why not use localStorage.setitem and setting the localStorage first, and then using the get method

Because it would overwrite localstorage with default data every time

> why is the code parsed?

localStorage can only store strings.

Complex data structures (like arrays) must be serialised to strings before they can be stored.

Since they are serialised, they need to be deserialised when you pull them out of localStorage.